# How to filter multiple nested arrays with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I have an array nested with an array of objects, the problem is that I don't understand how to filter the entire property by `title` at once.

[image]

At the moment, filtering for the `title` property works fine for me, but it only works for the top level, that is, it does not work inside the `elems` array.

At the moment, my code looks like this

```
state: {
    searchValue: "",

    categories: [
        {
            title: "about",
            open: false,
            elems: [{ title: "portfolio" }],
        },
        {
            title: "services",
            open: false,
            elems: [{ title: "jobs" }],
        },
    ],
},

getters: {
    categories(state) {
        return state.categories.filter(item => {
            return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(state.searchValue.toLowerCase())
        })
    }
}
```

And in the end, for a better understanding, I would like to tell what I want to achieve when the user enters the word **about** or **portfolio** into the **input**, for example, I want to show the **first object** if the word jobs or **services** is entered, I want to show the second object, but again, the `title` property of the first level works for me, but the `title` property inside the `elems` array does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for nested array:

```js
let searchValue = "about"

const categories = [
  {title: "about", open: false, elems: [{ title: "portfolio" }],},
  {title: "services", open: false, elems: [{ title: "jobs" }, { title: "about" }],},
]

function cats(state) {
  return state.filter(item => {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) ||
      item.elems.some(e => e.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
  })
}

console.log(cats(categories))
```